# A branch branched-out from master still contains code from the old renamed branch

Tags: git

I have a local branch named `sprint1`. I renamed it to `sprint1-complete`.

Now I created a new branch from `master` (because I want to work off code from master in this new branch) using `git checkout -b sprint1` and named it `sprint1`. Unfortunately, `sprint1` still contains code from the deleted sprint1 branch instead of code from master.

Need to say, that I only experience this when I clone the branch. At the upstream, sprint1 contains code from master.

Now my question is, does this mean that the ref is not updated when I renamed or deleted the local branch?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: if you name it something other than sprint1 does it still contains contains code from the old deleted sprint1 ?

Comment: You probably created the new `sprint1` off the tip of `sprint1-complete` instead of off the tip of `master`. To provide more information, run `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all -n 10` and post the output in your question.

Comment: yea, first you checkout to master `git checkout ` and then `git checkout -b sprint1`